# ARKit + SceneKit: not able to move node anchored to face

Tags: position, scenekit, arkit, tracking, face

EDIT:  [link to project](https://github.com/yotamoo/CodeExample)

I have a simple box anchored to the user's face, and I'd like to change it's XYZ position with 3 different `UISlider` controls. I have tried several methods, but nothing happens. The object stays static.

I think the code can speak better:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import ARKit
import SceneKit

class SceneKitViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    var rootNode: SCNNode!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else { return }
        
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.session.delegate = self
        sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        
        rootNode = box
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedFaces = 1
        configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
        sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [])
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }
    
    var box: SCNNode {
        let box = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: box)
        node.position = SCNVector3(0,0,0)
        return node
    }
    
    @IBAction func setXAxis(sender: UISlider) {
        setNewPosition(SCNVector3(sender.value, rootNode.position.y, rootNode.position.z))
    }
    
    @IBAction func setYAxis(sender: UISlider) {
        setNewPosition(SCNVector3(rootNode.position.x, sender.value, rootNode.position.z))
    }
    
    @IBAction func setZAxis(sender: UISlider) {
        setNewPosition(SCNVector3(rootNode.position.x, rootNode.position.y, sender.value))
    }
    
    @IBAction func setScale(sender: UISlider) {
        rootNode.scale = SCNVector3(sender.value, sender.value, sender.value)
    }
    
    private func setNewPosition(_ vector: SCNVector3) {
        // 
        print("moving to \(vector)")
//        rootNode.position = vector
//        rootNode.localTranslate(by: vector)
        updatePositionOf(rootNode, withPosition: vector)
    }
    
    func updatePositionOf(_ node: SCNNode, withPosition position: SCNVector3) {
        var translationMatrix = matrix_identity_float4x4
        translationMatrix.columns.3.x = position.x
        translationMatrix.columns.3.y = position.y
        translationMatrix.columns.3.z = position.z
        
        node.transform = SCNMatrix4(translationMatrix)
    }
}

extension SceneKitViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        if let _ = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor {
            return rootNode
        }
        return nil
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        
    }
}
```

What am I not understanding here? Thanks!

Comment: What's the issue you are running into? Does it not work as expected? What exactly happens?

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: what says the print statement, that should output the new vector? does this work?

Comment: You mean `moving to xyz`? It prints the vector I sent, but nothing happens

Comment: can you share the proj?

Comment: Done! please look on top. Thanks :)

Comment: I installed your proj on my iPhone 11 Pro Max, and it seems everything works okay. I can see the goggles on my nose and when I change the sliders the goggles move up/down, right/left and scales without any issue. The only thing I changed was line 87 in RealityKitViewController => ...activityItems: items as [Any], applicationActivities...